# Convert Width of a textbox to x,y cordinates

Tags: wpf, textbox, geometry, coordinates, pixel

How to convert the width of a text box into y-axis (X,Y) coordinates. For E.g if the Height and  width of the text box is 100 and 100 and X&Y Coordinates of the text box is (400,400) then i need to get the coordinates value from the width and height. Is it possible to it and i am using text box in WPF

Comment: Unless I am mistaken about the question, you are asking to do some very basic math?

Comment: you want the coordinate of each corner of the textbox?

Comment: no @Jehof I need the end coordinate specifically X axis